# Get process creation date-time in OSX with C / C++

Tags: c++, c, macos, process

Given a process id, what is the best way to find the process's creation date-time using C/C++ ?

Comment: Not sure; you should see how `top` and `ps` do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the [top](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-100.1.2/) and [ps](http://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158/ps/) source code (in particular, [`libtop.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/top/top-100.1.2/libtop.c)).

I *think* the following call should be what you need:

```
int proc_pidbsdinfo(proc_t p, struct proc_bsdinfo *pbsd, int zombie);
```

From `<sys/proc_info.h>`:

```
struct proc_bsdinfo {
...
    struct timeval      pbi_start;
...
}
```

Unfortunately there is no public interface for process inspection so the calls are not only version-dependant but also likely to change in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple utility demonstrating how to do this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Check arguments
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: %s PID\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Parse and validate PID argument
    errno = 0;
    char *end = NULL;
    long pid = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
    if (errno != 0 || end == argv[1] || end == NULL || *end != 0 || ((pid_t)pid) != pid) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: bad PID argument: %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Get process info from kernel
    struct kinfo_proc info;
    int mib[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, (int)pid };
    size_t len = sizeof info;
    memset(&info,0,len);
    int rc = sysctl(mib, (sizeof(mib)/sizeof(int)), &info, &len, NULL, 0);
    if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: sysctl failed with errno=%d\n", argv[0], errno);
        return 1;
    }

    // Extract start time and confirm process exists
    struct timeval tv = info.kp_proc.p_starttime;
    if (tv.tv_sec == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: no such PID %d\n", argv[0], (int)pid);
        return 1;
    }

    // Convert to string - no \n because ctime() result is already \n-terminated
    printf("PID %d started at %s", (int)pid, ctime(&(tv.tv_sec)));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it: `clang -o procstart procstart.c`

Example of running it:

```
$ ./procstart $$
PID 37675 started at Sat Apr  9 20:01:55 2022
```

Note the `sysctl` API this is calling is undocumented and as such (at least in theory) subject to change at any time. In practice however, it has been rather stable across releases, so while nobody can predict what Apple might do in the future, I think the risk of them breaking this is low.