# How to get process start time on OS X in C++ programm

Tags: c++, macos

I am writing cross-platform C++ application and need to get process start time value. On Windows we have `GetProcessTimes()` function for this purpose. On Linux `proc/self/stat` file contains this information. What is the right way on OS X?

Answer (score 5):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605649/3088216). 
To sum up: look at [ps](https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-158/ps/) source code for implementation that would work on Linux and OS X at least.

PS: you can get it from CLI with the following command:

```
ps -ax -o etime,command -c | grep $YOUR_PROC_NAME
```

[source](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20121127064752309)